# Pyspark Mutual Information Calculation

Tags: python, pyspark, statistics, window-functions, feature-selection

I am trying to calculate with Pyspark the mutual information of a continuous variable and a categorical one, without having to bin the continuous variable (cf. https://journals.plos.org/plosone/articleid=10.1371/journal.pone.0087357).

The formula from the article above requires that I calculate, on each point of my categorical variable, the K nearest neighbours in terms of a distance defined on the continuous variable, only accounting the data points from the same categorical class as the current point. A good value of K is usually 3.
For example on this dataset: ( please note there is no redundancy, I only showed 2 features here). 
[Dataset sorted by metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ekb6.png)

If k = 3 and I am on the point A = (0.023, Orange), I find the 3 nearest neighbours in terms of metric with categories = Orange, so it will be:
(0, Orange), (0, Orange), (0.11, Orange).
Once I have found these neighbours, I need to find the distance of the furthest one and define it as my diameter around A (here 0.11 - 0.023), and then find the number of neighbours in the whole dataset, which I will call m.

Once we have the diameter and m for each point, we use them to calculate a number Ni for each point, and we do the mean  over the whole dataset.

I am having trouble to achieve the code that loops over the points in my pyspark dataset ( .rdd.map) and does the whole operation of finding the diameter and the number of neighbours m. I tried using window functions but it was hard to define the range since the range is not constant.

Thank you.